# Find a function on objective c to write system messages as actionscript trace

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3

I'm starting to learn Objective C and I wonder if there is any similar function to actionscript **trace** to show messages in a console.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Each called method has implicit `self` (as object) and `_cmd` (as SEL) parameters. Hence you can do this in `Foo` class:

```
- (void)foo {
    NSLog(@"-[%@ %@] custom log", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

This is off top of my head. And, of course there are various macros defined for such shortcut. The one I'm using is [from here](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/).